# C: Collect user input with while loop and store in array

Tags: c

I have this coding project that I have been stuck on for some time now.  I am not really familiar with coding in C, more with Java.

Here is my code:

```
char *array[20];
int linecount = 0;
bool c = true;

array[0] = (char*)malloc(96 *sizeof(char));
// array[0] = "temp";
while(c){
    array[linecount] = (char*)malloc(96 *sizeof(char)); 
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets(array[linecount], sizeof(array[linecount]), stdin);
    if(strcmp(array[linecount], "") == 10) c = false;
    linecount++;
}
for(int i = 0; i < linecount; i++){
    printf("%d %s",i, array[i]);
}
printf("Done");
```

The part that I am stuck on is storing user input from the console into an array of strings.  I've looked at a lot of answers on stackoverflow and I find that there are so many different answers out there that I get overwhelmed.  So if you could answer in the simplest terms how and what the code does it would help me a lot.

So I created an array of pointers with a fixed length of 20 just to start off and a while loop.  But when I run the program, it works sort of how I want it to.  When I type any spaces in the input it prints "Enter a string:" a number of times.

Comment: `fgets` stores the \n at the end of the line, therefore `strcmp(array[linecount], "") == 10` is pointless and comparing with 10 is even more pointless. Also `sizeof(array[linecount])`  is not what you think it is. You want `96` instead. There are most likely more problems.

Comment: Thanks, it seemed to work when I changed it to 96.  Also why is strcmp(array[linecount], "") == 10 pointless? I am trying to check if the string is empty and I found other posts saying to use strcmp.  When I print it while comparing it to an empty string I get 10 that's why I decided to compare it with 10.

Comment: Explain what `strcmp(array[linecount], "") == 10` is supposed to do? What is the magic number 10?

Comment: `sizeof(array[linecount])` is the size of the pointer itself (4 or 8 bytes, depending on the platform). It is not the size of the referenced memory buffer. When using dynamic memory allocation (e.g. `malloc`), you must remember the size of the buffer yourself. You can't simply use `sizeof` to determine it.

Comment: Check return value of fgets. It might have returned -1 and written nothing to the buffer.

Comment: In the first iteration of your loop you overwrite the pointer assigned to `array[0]` before the loop, in effect leaking the memory allocated by that `malloc`. No need to assign `array[0]` anything before the loop. You should also make sure the loop ends when `linecount` reaches `20`. `c` will happily break something if you do a buffer overflow. And don't forget to have a `free` for each `malloc`. Typically I recommend people coming from Java to c or c++ to get a good tutorial as if it was their first language. Java has more in common with Python or Lisp, even if there is similar syntax.